# How to grab the first row from a column and last row from another column from a group by

Tags: python, dataframe, group-by

I have a df with 3 columns. Tenant, start and end as columns

| Tenant | Start | End |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x | 10 | 20 |
| x | 20 | 30 |
| x | 30 | 40 |
| y | 15 | 30 |
| y | 30 | 45 |

I want to group by tenant and get the first value from start and last value from end to. The results df should look like this:

| Tenant | Start | End |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x | 10 | 40 |
| y | 15 | 45 |

this is my code but its not correct:

```
df_login_merge_final = df_login_merge_final.groupby('tenant').first().reset_index()
df_login_summary = df_login_merge_final[['tenant','outage_start']]
df_login_merge_final_1 = df_login_merge_final.groupby('tenant').last().reset_index()
df_login_summary_1 = df_login_merge_final_1[['tenant','outage_end']]
df_login_summary_master = pd.merge(df_login_summary,df_login_summary_1,on=['tenant'],how ='inner')
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a Q&A site; "*I want...*" isn't a question. Can you share the code you've written in an attempt to meet this requirement as a [mre], being sure to include a succinct explanation of where *specifically* you're getting stuck? See also: [ask]

Comment: "*not sure if its correct*" What do you mean? Have you run it? If so, what happens? What was your expectation? If not, why not...?

Comment: You have to be quite specific here. Depending on your expectations and how this data is structured in the first place, this could either be a one-liner or more than just a couple of lines to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with one `groupby` function and applying the aggregation functions `min` and `max` on each column that you need using this syntax:

```
df.groupby(['Tenant']).agg({'Start': min, 'End': max})
```

Comment: This would be the ideal solution IFF he was looking for min and max. If he was looking for the first and last values and those values don't coincide with the min and the max, this will fail. For that, he has to use `"first"` and `"last"` as his agg functions.

Comment: Yes, absolutely agreed. I was supposing he needed min and max @NullDev.

Comment: @RamiShehadah Please accept the answer if it's what you need. You have a history of not accepting good answers to your questions.